# Is there a low level Network library to sniff and change network traffic?

Tags: c#, .net, api, networking, sniffing

I am looking for a way to sniff network packets and encode them with C# (in summary: alter network traffic).

I don't know how to explain my request but I need something like "Keyboard Hook".

**Is there any library or software in .net or Windows API?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible by default. But there are plenty of third party libraries that enable you to do that. Take a look at

- [SharpPcap - A Packet Capture Framework for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12458/SharpPcap-A-Packet-Capture-Framework-for-NET)
- [Packet Capture and Analayzer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4194/Packet-Capture-and-Analayzer)
- [Pcap.Net](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Those are all layers over, or rewrites of, libpcap. It's a packet capture facility. It doesn't allow you to change packets.

Comment: Taken from the first link - "Injecting low-level network packets on a given interface". These libraries are as close as you can get to having "full access" on the packets going through your NIC in C#. I could have thrown WinDivert in the list but since there is a C# tag that wouldn't be helpful.

Comment: I saw WinDivert !that is exactly what i want ! But I don t understand  "driver must be digitally signed" what does it  means ? every users should do these to use my application ?http://reqrypt.org/windivert-doc.html#introduction

Comment: This should give you an insight on what digital signatures are http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature . Assuming the licence of WinDivert allows you, you can distribute the already signed file.

Comment: working with WinDivert is too difficult for me! I know A little a bout c++ ! is there any ready library in .net to do same work in C#  ?

Comment: Not one that I know off, as I mentioned on the first comment the libraries above are as close as you can get in C#. Other than that you will need to get a bit creative.