# Route all traffic through internal proxy

Tags: c#, sockets, proxy, winsock2

I embed a Flash SWF file into my C# application which connects to the internet. Is it possible to route all traffic through an internal proxy (which I would set up in the program too)? Currently I'm hooking the `send` and `recv` functions, but it gets more and more complicated (threading comes into the game).

Comment: What is an "internal proxy"? What traffic (which protocols, which ports / programs, which direction) do you want to capture exactly? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Internal proxy = server which receives and traffics and just resend it to the original listener. Traffic is in and out, the protocol doesn't matter, it's custom. What I want to do is to read all (and sometimes modify) data that goes in and out. Currently I'm doing this via a send/recv-function-hook which works pretty well, but gets complicated when threading comes into the game.

Comment: That's not trivial. See for example [Is there a low level Network library to sniff and change network traffic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614123/is-there-a-low-level-network-library-to-sniff-and-change-network-traffic). Are you looking for a tool, or do you want to write something yourself?

Comment: Oh, wow. That seems to be complicated. Yes, this is what I've searched for. Thanks!